# Symfony/Doctrine, 121 error : Duplicate key on write or update

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

With [Symfony 5](https://symfony.com/) and Doctrine, I use `php bin/console d:s:u --force` command for update my datbase. I don't use migrations, even though I know I ought to.

Since a few days I have this error :

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `prod`.`translation` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

I think this error is due to some bad manipulation I did from PhpMyAdmin (delete the columns for rename).

When I run the `php bin/console d:s:u --dump-sql` command, I get this:

```
ALTER TABLE translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B469456FE934951A FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES exercise (id);
ALTER TABLE translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B469456FCAD30DCE FOREIGN KEY (pro_price_title_id) REFERENCES pro_price (id);
ALTER TABLE translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B469456F8DDF23AA FOREIGN KEY (pro_price_content_id) REFERENCES pro_price (id);
ALTER TABLE translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B469456FB03A8386 FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES app_user (id);
ALTER TABLE translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B469456FC76F1F52 FOREIGN KEY (deleted_by_id) REFERENCES app_user (id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_B469456FE934951A ON translation (exercise_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_B469456FCAD30DCE ON translation (pro_price_title_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_B469456F8DDF23AA ON translation (pro_price_content_id);
```

As you can see, only INDEX/FK are missing. I even searched my entire database using `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';` and they are not present - So I don't understand the term *duplicate*

Do you know how to solve this problem? I have read that it is "only" necessary to change the name of the INDEX/FK but with Doctrine it is not possible and I prefer not to touch the configuration.

Thanks

Comment: The error message "errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update" is not from Doctrine but from the database. A duplicate key is created in a table during an update. Something in your application (entities) does not match the database schema. I recommend always using Doctrine migration and never fiddling manually with the database schema. 

You should regenerate the database schema with doctrine migration. So you have to reset the database and then only work with Doctrine-Migration. That is my advice.